# JSON getting object inside a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get an object from inside a JSON but I can't. It only gives me `undefined`.
But when I check the result on the console it gives me the right results.

Here is my JSON

```
{
    users: [
            {
            userID: "151",
            userFirstname: "first",
            userMiddlename: "middle",
            userLastname: "latname",
            userAddress: "qewasd",
            userContactNumber: "123456",
            userRole: "role",
            userName: "user",
            userPassword: "pass",
            userEmail: "test@gmail.com",
            userPitch: "Very good",
            userExperience: "5",
            userFirm: "Sample",
            userRollNo: "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://batz.web/Sandbox/details.php?userID=151', function (results){
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = results.userID;
        console.log(results);
    });

});
```

Comment: It should be `results.users[0].userID`

Comment: That's not JSON. (If it *were* JSON, it would be invalid JSON.) JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @H77 - Wow, that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok look at your json, **userID** is not a direct child of the results object, which means 
 **It will always return null every time you try to get the value of undefined field**

You first need to get the array's content with the key(left side of full colon), as the array is in **"users" field(or key)** ,userId is not still in the array's field, so you gotta point with an index(e.g,0,1,2,...) to get the object which contain **userID**

```
...
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = results.users[0].userId;
...
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KheinHtoo/xb0pbmee/2/)